# WCF service return base class only

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on a WCF service and trying to cleanup code.  Issue I'm running into is I have a base data type I want to send as results from the service to the client; however in the service code itself it will mostly make use of classes derived on the base with additional properties for processing.  The client has no reason to know about these at all.

Right now I can get this working but only if I define the derived classes in the shared library.  I do not want them in there as they are specific solely to the service.

Below is example to show the problem.  All three files are in separate projects in the same solution.

***Common.IPersonService.cs***

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Common
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPersonService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetPersonById")]        
        Person GetPersonById(int id);
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

***WcfClient.Program.cs***

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Common;

namespace WcfClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8001/WcfTest/");
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IPersonService>(binding, endpoint);

            IPersonService service = null;

            try
            {
                service = factory.CreateChannel();

                Person result = service.GetPersonById(5);
                Console.WriteLine(result.Name);

                ((ICommunicationObject)service).Close();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***WcfService.Program.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Common;

namespace WcfService
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Person")]
    public class Contact : Person
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService)))
            {
                serviceHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Service started");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class PersonService : IPersonService
    {

        private Dictionary<int, Contact> _testData = new Dictionary<int, Contact>();

        public PersonService()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                _testData.Add(i + 1, new Contact()
                {
                    Id = i + 1,
                    Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Address = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                });
            }
        }

        public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPersonService), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:8001/WcfTest/");

            config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
        }

        public Person GetPersonById(int id)
        {
            return _testData[id];
        }

        public Person GetValueByKey(string key)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception received is the following:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:00:59.9780000'.

Now if I move the Contact class from the WcfService project and put it in the Common project it will work.  As said though I'd prefer not to muddy a common library with items specific to the service implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to have the `Contact` class in a shared library, because both server AND client need to know how to serialize and deserialize the transferred data. The shared library contains CONTRACT's between server and client, operation AND data contracts. That's not 'muddy'.

Comment: @KBO The muddy part is that 'Contact' class in my actual program has only data and functions that the server process itself needs and should not be transmitted ever via the service to a client.  So adding that class that the client should never know about at all to a shared library is muddy.  The 'Contact' class simply naturally expanded on the base class so made sense to inherit.  For the time being I've gotten rid of the inheritance and just made Person a member of Contact so it can be sent on it's own.

Comment: Turn on wcf message logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging. There will no doubt be more details about the exception